# Writing R file into Stata with paste function

Tags: r, stata

I am trying to write the `R` file into `Stata` with `Stata` file name generated using the `paste` function:

```
# x is any data frame 
library(foreign)
year<-2010
z<-paste("data", year, sep=".")
write.dta(x, “z.dta")

R gives me the error: 
Error: unexpected input in "write.dta(x, “"
```

I would greatly appreciate if you could provide some hint to fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
write.dta(x, paste(z, '.dta', sep=''))
```

This will produce a file name `data.2010.dta`

Even shorter using `paste0` function

```
write.dta(x, paste0(z, '.dta'))
```

Comment: Your double quotation marks appear to be different ASCII characters.

Comment: Thanks Jilber for the solution!